# NSDateFormatter from string is nil

Tags: ios, swift, nsdate, nsdateformatter

I'm trying to make a date from a string. The string is: "2015-09-09T00:00:00.000Z".

I have an NSDateFormatter dateFormat of:

```
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'Z'"
dateFormatter.timeZone = NSTimeZone(forSecondsFromGMT: 0)
dateFormatter.locale = NSLocale(localeIdentifier: "us_US")
```

It formats correctly, but my other attempts to simply it returns nil.

I've tried "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm'Z'" and even "yyyy-MM-dd". Both return nil.

I would like it to read 09-10-2015 at 6:30PM.
Can someone offer some advice?

Comment: Update your question with real code that returns `nil`. The code you posted doesn't return anything.

Comment: Don't escape the Z = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ", set locale to "en_US_POSIX" and calendar  to NSCalendar(calendarIdentifier: NSCalendarIdentifierISO8601)

Comment: What is the timezone offset at your location. Why are you expecting a date with UTC time 00:00 return 6:30 pm ? is the offset time 5 and a half hours?

Comment: Sorry Leo, I was just using 6:30pm as an example.

Comment: @yamski please include the input string, and the corresponding time zone. Your date looks like ISO8601 at UTC time (Z means UTC time)

Comment: Is it on iOS 9 ? Because I have the same problem as you. My method returns nil NSDate on iOS 9, but works great on iOS 8 and earlier ! I found a subject here with an issue on iOS 9 and NSDateFormatter: https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/16783

Answer (score 0):

I think you should set locale to "en_US_POSIX"

```
dateFormatter.dateFormat = @"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZ"
dateFormatter.locale = NSLocale(localeIdentifier:@"en_US_POSIX")
dateFormatter.timeZone = NSTimeZone(forSecondsFromGMT:0)
dateFormatter.dateFromString(dateString)
```

Note that `dateFormatter.dateFromString(dateString)` may not give you an output because the string that you pass may not be a date string.